# Attempting to return a fraction (as a float) in Java

Tags: java, string, floating-point, return

In this function:

```
public float cgRatio(String dna) {
    //initialize count to be 0
    int count = 0;
    //for each character in the string
    //if character == 'C' or 'G' increment count
    for (int i = 0; i < dna.length(); i++) {
        char c = dna.charAt(i);
        if (c == 'C' || c == 'G') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    //return the ratio of C & G in DNA strand
    return count/dna.length();
}
```

with my test function:

```
public void testFindGene() {
    String[] dnaStrands = new String[6];
    dnaStrands[0] = "AGCATGGTAACCAATAAGCGTTAAGCCAT";
    dnaStrands[1] = "AATAATGGCATGGCCAATGAATGCGTAACCGATTAA";
    dnaStrands[2] = "ATAATGCGGAATTGACATGGTA";
    dnaStrands[3] = "AGCATGGTAACCAATTAGCGTTAAGCCAT";
    dnaStrands[4] = "AATAATGGCATGGCCAATGAATTGACGTAACCGATTAA";
    dnaStrands[5] = "ATAATGCGGAATCTAGACATGGTA";

    for (int i = 0; i < dnaStrands.length - 1; i++) {
        String gene = findGene(dnaStrands[i], 0);
        System.out.println("The DNA strand is: \"" + dnaStrands[i] + "\"");
        System.out.println("Gene: " + gene);
        System.out.println("CG ratio of gene sequence is: " + String.format("%.02f", cgRatio(gene)));
    }
}
```

My cgRatio return value is always 0.00.  If I return just the count, I get accurate results in the form of a float.  So that means my cgRatio function fails on this line:

```
    //return the ratio of C & G in DNA strand
    return count/dna.length();
```

Can you not return a fraction in Java?  If you can, how can I fix this?  If you cannot, why and what is an alternative solution?

Comment: Have you tried casting?

Comment: A Google search on "why does my division return 0 in Java?" returns a _lot_ of answers. Turns out this "feature" of Java has puzzled tens of thousands of programmers, maybe more. :)

Comment: When I add (float) in front of the fraction it works.  So if I need to do that for a fraction why did I not need to do that when I was returning just the count (when I instantiated count as an integer)

Comment: Java is happy to return an integer value casted as a float, the problem is that because your fraction is less than one, when you divide one integer by another, Java then rounds down to get an integer, thus you return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more clarification as to what is actually happening, the code

```
return count/dna.length();
```

is doing integer math *then* casting the result as a float.

For example if count is 5 and dna.length() returns 7,

5 / 7 = 0.714 which equals 0 when doing integer math (it rounds down to the nearest integer value).

So your code is essentially doing float(0) which gets your result of 0.00.

Comment: Very clear and easy to understand.  Makes sense as to why if I return just count, it appears to work but as a fraction < 1 it will round down to 0 and print 0.0.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

try doing as ,

```
return (float)count/dna.length();
```

**count** and **length** both are int that is why you are getting like that.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring count as a float would also solve the issue. Integer division yield an integer and omits fractions.

```
float count = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast your variables before dividing `return (double)count/(double)dna.length();` Java is making it integer division because both are ints.

Comment: you would not need the second cast here on dna.length(), as a floating point divided by an integer will not use integer math.